# Stop Jenkins trying to run as root

Tags: python, jenkins, invoke

This is an odd one.

We have a Jenkins server which runs fine for the most part, but fails on a python build. We run the build using `invoke test`, invoke being the python lib.

From what I can tell it is trying to run as root, or at least in the `/root` directory (n.b., not `/`, `/root`) which it doesn't have permission to do.

Here is the relevant line of the log:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/.invoke.yaml'
```

My question is why? and how do I stop it?

Here is the test command being run:

```
@task
def test():
    # Install dependencies
    install_requirements('dev-requirements.txt')

    # Run tests
    run("RUN_ENV=test nosetests --verbose --stop --with-xcoverage --with-xunit --cover-package=yt_api_auth --cover-inclusive")

    # Test package generation
    package_name, dist = get_names()

    package()
    run('pip install -U dist/{}.tar.gz'.format(dist))
```

Comment: Totally off-topic, but from your title I thought you were having a problem with an employee!

Comment: @KennethK. Ha brilliant! Do you think SO is a good place for people management solutions?